# Python BeautifulSoup and HTML with unusual spaces

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to update product prices by scraping their prices from a website. However I have reached an unusual html formatting which is giving me some trouble. I am trying to return the price without the spaces. Currently my code brings in all the spaces.

```
<p class='product__price'> == $0
    <span class='visuallyhidden'>Regular price</span>
    "


             £9.99

            " == $0
</p>
```

I am trying the following:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")

for product in soup.find_all('div', class_="product-wrapper"):
    # Get product name
    product_title = product.find('p', class_='h4 product__title').text
    # Get product price
    product_price = product.find('p', class_='product__price').text
    product_price.strip()
```

But unfortunately using the .strip() method does not work and the script returns the prices with a bunch of space and "Regular price".

Any ideas on how I can get exactly "£9.99" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contents` and get the last element and then split string with "

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data='''<p class='product__price'> == $0
    <span class='visuallyhidden'>Regular price</span>
    "


             £9.99

            " == $0
</p>'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
items=soup.select_one('.product__price').contents
print(items[-1].split('"')[1].strip())
```

Comment: Thanks ! This did work indeed. Much appreciate the help.

Comment: Sure! How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this does not work is because the `p` element contains two children:

- A `span` element
- A `text` node

When you cann `.text` on the parent `p` element you will drop the "span" tag. In addition to this, the content contains quotes which will make `strip()` ignore the spaces inside those quotes.

To solve the problem you must first isolate the text content from the `span` node, which you can do by diving into the `span` node using `.children`.

Finally, you can tell `.strip()` which characters to remove.

So, *assumning the structure inside the `p` element is always like this* we can do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = """
<div>
<p class='product__price'>
    <span class='visuallyhidden'>Regular price</span>
    "


             £9.99

            "
</p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for product in soup.find_all('div'):
    # Get product price
    product_price = product.find('p', class_='product__price')
    raw_data = list(product_price.children)[-1]

    # Remove spaces, newlines and quotes
    cleaned = raw_data.strip(' \n"')
    print(repr(cleaned))
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This worked beautifully. Really appreciate the help. Perhaps you can help me with a follow-on question I had on this? I have updated my question to include your code suggestions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188342/looping-through-web-pages

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
product_price = product_price.strip().replace("  ","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This does improve the situation. It has removed all the spaces after the price, but not before it. Any idea how to the spaces before the price as well as the 'Regular price' text?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach: how about regex?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """<div><p class='product__price'> == $0
    <span class='visuallyhidden'>Regular price</span>
    "


             £9.99

            " == $0
</p></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for product in soup.find_all('div'):
    # Get product price
    product_price = product.find('p', class_='product__price').text
    # Regex
    price = re.search("(£\d*\.?\d*)", product_price)
    # Print only when there is a match
    if price: print(price[0])
```

Comment: thanks for the help. The regex does work. Appreciate the help.