# Looping through web pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am running a script to update product prices by scraping them from a website. The script should scrape all names and prices for a given page and then move on to the next page. However, instead of moving on to the next page it keeps looping through the same page for some reason. I tried many variations of the code but it still keeps happening.

Here is my code:

```
page_B = 1
url_B = 'https://website/section/food-drink?page=1/'  # Initial url

while page_B < 15:
    req = Request(url_B, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})
    web_page = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")

    for product in soup.find_all('div', class_="product-wrapper"):
        # Get product name
        product_title = product.find('p', class_='h4 product__title').text
        # Get product price
        product_price = product.find('p', class_='product__price')
        raw_data = list(product_price.children)[-1]
        # Remove spaces, newlines and quotes from prices
        clean_price = raw_data.strip(' \n"')

        print(product_title)
        print(clean_price)

        csv_writer.writerow([product_title, product_price])

    url_base = url_B.split(str(page_B))
    page_B += 1
    new_url = url_base[0] + str(page_B) + '/'
    url_B = new_url

csv_file.close()
```

The last portion of the code is where I instruct the script to update the url for the next page. When I run this program it is printing me product names and prices 15 times for the same page. I suspect the issue has something to do with local vs global variables, but I'm quite new to programming, so still a bit confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This answer is very difficult to answer without seeing the input data (the HTML you want to parse). Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At a quick glance, the code looks fine. So it may be related to the HTML data. Without an example we cannot give you an informed feedback

Comment: I have run several print statements on url_base, page_B, new_url, and url_B and indeed it seems the link is updated correctly, but somehow the loop wont work.

Comment: I did get some time running it now and it works for me. Maybe the problem is in a different part of the code you omitted. Read again the link I gave above about giving examples. Often, just by rewriting the code into an MCVE the error pops out to me. It has similarities with "Rubber Duck Debugging".

Comment: I restructured the code a bit with functions (as an exercise) and created a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/exhuma/a1fc740b34b404e832be9627ec59b66d) for you to have a look at. As you mention that you are new to programming, I've added comments liberally which may be informative. This is not intended as answer as the code works for me.

Comment: @exhuma thank you so much for this. I just checked your code and it was really helpful to help me in my learning process. I'll be implementing all your suggestions. In the end, the issue why it wasn't working was unexpected (and simple really).

Comment: Strangely, the last '/' at the end of the url somehow made the address always go back to the first page irrespective of what page number was in the url.

Comment: So 'website/section/food-drink?page=1/' would return the 1st page, and 'website/section/food-drink?page=2/' would also return the 1st page, but 'website/section/food-drink?page=2' returns the second page. Who would have thought.

Comment: You're welcome. Given that you figured out the solution, you could add an answer to your question and accept it. So in the off-chance that someone comes along 10 years later and stumbles accross this, the answer could help that person ;) Have a look [at the URI spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3). It shows no `/` at the end. So your constructed string was wrong (which I didn't spot). This should be the answer. If you add it, I will definitely upvote it.

Comment: @exhuma To be honest, I have just discovered that '/' at the end of a website url makes a difference. I always thought that it had no effect unless followed by an additional path. As agreed I will post an answer to my question below.

Answer (score 0):

Use python format() function.

```
page_B = 1
url_B = 'https://website/section/food-drink?page={}/'  # Initial url

while page_B < 15:
    req = Request(url_B.format(page_B), headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'})
    web_page = urlopen(req).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, "html.parser")
    page_B=page_B+1
```

Comment: While this is an interesting point, it does not answer the question though.

Comment: Can you share your url?

Comment: I have run several print statements on url_base, page_B, new_url, and url_B and indeed it seems the link is updated correctly, but somehow the loop wont work.

Comment: Website is not accessible right now it reaches maximum hit.I will give it a try later.

Comment: I have figured what the issue is! Strangely, the last '/' at the end of the url somehow made the address always go back to the first page irrespective of what page number was in the url.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the support, and this was a big lesson learned.

Comment: So 'website/section/food-drink?page=1/' would return the 1st page, and 'website/section/food-drink?page=2/' would also return the 1st page, but 'website/section/food-drink?page=2' returns the second page. Who would have thought.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured what the issue is! Strangely, the last '/' at the end of the url somehow made the address always go back to the first page irrespective of what page number was in the url.

So 'website/section/food-drink?page=1/' would return the 1st page, and 'website/section/food-drink?page=2/' would also return the 1st page, but 'website/section/food-drink?page=2' returns the second page.

I had always thought that the '/' at the end of a url was largely redundant unless followed by a path, but it turns out it is not.